# How do you add a new class to first child of <ul> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I am generating a style listing dynamically.
What is the jquery function to add a class to the first

using jquery.

```
<ul>
 <li class="add-class-here"></li>
 <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Post the relevant HTML/CSS/JS supporting this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a combination of the `:first` psuedo-class and the `addClass()` method:

```
$('ul li:first').addClass('someClass');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
Dear actully I want add css class to first level li
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector:

```
$('#list_id li:first').addClass('classname');
```

Answer (score 1):

without using jquery

With - CSS Global

```
li:first-child{conduct01}
li{conduct02}
li:last-child {conduct03}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('ul li:first').addClass('some_class');
```

Comment: -1. That selects each `li` element that is a direct child of `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is static, it is better to specify it in CSS3 using `first-child` or `first-of-type` selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need jQuery for this ?

You could do it using CSS first-child pseudo element.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp